# Java directly jumping to else statement?

Tags: java

I have been trying to code a train reservation system which is my school project, but I don't know why my `if` statement is directly jumping to the `else` even if the `if` statement is true. Removing the `else` statement fixes the problem, but I need it because it is mandatory to print an appropriate error message.

```
for (int j=0;j<len;j++)
    {
        if (trainno[j]==tno)
        {
            stna = trainname[j];
            stno = tno;
            sto = origin[j];
            std = destination[j];
            stf = fare[j];
        }
        else if (tno==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Thanks for visiting our website!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Wong input! Try again....");
        } //I wasn't able to assign an error message due to some problem because of which it was always jumping to else statement even if trainno[j] was equal to tno, do tell me if you can find the problem
    }
```

Whole code

```
import java.io.*;
class PROJECT
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    void main () throws IOException
    {
    System.out.println("Welcome to IRCTC Railway Reservation System! Please proceed further to book your train!");
    System.out.println();
    String[] trainname = {"Rajdhani EXP", "AUG Kranti EXP", "Chennai EXP", "Aravali EXP", "Paschim EXP", "Gareeb Rath", "Punjab Mail", "Dehradun EXP", "Swaraj EXP", "Aravali EXP"};
    int[] trainno = {57835, 87612, 15384, 16512, 65265, 51654, 31543, 56416, 85484, 78455};
    String[] origin = {"Mumbai", "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Goa", "Durg", "Aligarh", "Jaipur", "Bhuj"};
    String[] destination = {"Surat", "Delhi", "Chennai", "Mumbai", "Ajmer", "Mumbai", "Bikaner", "Agra", "Madurai", "Buxar"};
    int[] fare = {650, 950, 1100, 1200, 1050, 600, 1100, 1250, 1300, 1100};
    int len = trainname.length;
    int len1 = trainno.length;
    int len2 = origin.length;
    int len3 = destination.length;
    int len4 = fare.length;
    String stna = "";
    int stno = 0;
    String sto = "";
    String std = "";
    int stf = 0;
    System.out.println("Train Name\t\tTrain No.\tOrigin\t        Destination\tFare");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(trainname[i]+"\t\t"+trainno[i]+"\t\t"+origin[i]+"\t\t"+destination[i]+"\t\t"+fare[i]); 
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter train no. to select train or enter 0 to exit :- ");
    int tno = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());
    for (int j=0;j<len;j++)
    {
        if (trainno[j]==tno)
        {
            stna = trainname[j];
            stno = tno;
            sto = origin[j];
            std = destination[j];
            stf = fare[j];
        }
        else if (tno==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Thanks for visiting our website!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Wong input! Try again....");
        } //I wasn't able to assign an error message due to some problem because of which it was always jumping to else statement even if trainno[j] was equal to tno, do tell me if you can find the problem
    }
    System.out.print("Enter number of passengers (max 10) :- ");
    int nopt = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine()); 
    if (nopt>10)
    {
        System.out.print("Uh-Oh! No. of passengers are more than 10, please try again");
        return;
    }
    String[] pn = new String[nopt];
    int[] age = new int[nopt];
    for (int k=0;k<nopt;k++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter passenger's name :- ");
        pn[k] = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter passenger's age :- ");
        age[k] = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());
        System.out.println();
    }
    double tf = (nopt*stf)*1.12;
    System.out.println("Booking Details :-");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("No. of passengers :- "+nopt);
    for (int z=0;z<nopt;z++)
    {
        System.out.println("Name of passenger travelling :- "+pn[z]);
    }
    System.out.println("Train Name :- "+stna);
    System.out.println("Train Number :- "+stno);
    System.out.println("Train Origin :- "+sto);
    System.out.println("Train Destination :- "+std);
    System.out.println("Train Fare/Person :- "+stf);
    System.out.println("Total Fare (12% tax added) :- "+tf);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Thanks for your booking! Your seats have been confirmed. Have a good day!");
}
}
```

Comment: I am a complete noob here :P :'(
I dont understand what you mean by this 

"so your exit input is wrong chosen. try something else but 0."

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this :

```
System.out.print("Enter train no. to select train or enter 0 to exit :- ");
int tno = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());

if(nto==0){
    System.out.println("Thanks for visiting our website!");
    return;
}else
{
    int j=0;
    while(trainno[j]!=tno && j<=trainno.length())
    {j++;
    }
     if (trainno[j]==tno)
     {
        stna = trainname[j];
        stno = tno;
        sto = origin[j];
        std = destination[j];
        stf = fare[j];
     }
     if(j>trainno.length())
     {
        System.out.print("Wong input! Try again....");
     } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a complete noob but how can i input a letter in int?

Comment: There's no need to input 'e' you can use '0' finely.
I edited the code here try it.

Comment: Since br is BufferedReader you can input anything and parse it. also try to check if it is not a number by Regex.. 
String.matches("[a-zA-Z]");

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `else if(tno==0)` and replace it with `else`. I dont think there is a requirement for the `else if` part.

Also, going ahead with what AMbrish said shall also make the code run.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some sop/log before the if statement to check if the boolean expression returns true or false and then see even after value being true whether it enters the else block. Copy the log and paste here then we can help further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code (shown below) then you should get your expected result:

```
    int tno = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    boolean foundTrain = false;
    if (tno == 0) {
        System.out.println("Thanks for visiting our website!");
        return;
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (trainno[j] == tno) {
                foundTrain = true;
                stna = trainname[j];
                stno = tno;
                sto = origin[j];
                std = destination[j];
                stf = fare[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!foundTrain) {
        System.out.print("Wong input! Try again....");
        return;
        // I wasn't able to assign an error message due to some problem because of which it was always jumping to else
        // statement even if trainno[j] was equal to tno, do tell me if you can find the problem
    }
```

Comment: As i said, i am learning all this in school and i cant use something i havent learn as my teacher is one big pain :'( so i have no idea what !foundTrain means

Comment: `!foundTrain` means that the boolean foundTrain is false.

Comment: @chsdk and Ambrish You both just saved me! Thanks a ton!